# Using SimpleXML to create an XML object from scratch

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

Is it possible to use PHP's SimpleXML functions to create an XML object from scratch?  Looking through the function list, there's ways to import an existing XML string into an object that you can then manipulate, but if I just want to generate an XML object programmatically from scratch, what's the best way to do that?

I figured out that you can use simplexml_load_string() and pass in the root string that you want, and then you've got an object you can manipulate by adding children... although this seems like kind of a hack, since I have to actually hardcode some XML into the string before it can be loaded.

I've done it using the [DOMDocument functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.domxml.php), although it's a little confusing because I'm not sure what the DOM has to do with creating a pure XML document... so maybe it's just badly named :-)

Answer (score 150, accepted):

Sure you can.  Eg.

```
<?php
$newsXML = new SimpleXMLElement("<news></news>");
$newsXML->addAttribute('newsPagePrefix', 'value goes here');
$newsIntro = $newsXML->addChild('content');
$newsIntro->addAttribute('type', 'latest');
Header('Content-type: text/xml');
echo $newsXML->asXML();
?>
```

Output

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<news newsPagePrefix="value goes here">
    <content type="latest"/>
</news>
```

Have fun.

Comment: Between this and @Stefan's and @PhiLho's answers, this seems the most simple and straightforward. At the same time, I wonder if the performance is different. The other two smell like fast code.

Comment: How do i save this as a xml file in the server? to make it available to my actionscript code?

Comment: @dreamwerx Maybe I'm missing something why isn't your `content` tag closed with `</content>`?

Comment: @Shackrock:it is closed, look at the "/" before the ">" of <content type="latest"/>

Comment: How to add some text between content tags. Say <content> Wow it works! </content>

Comment: @harishannam `addChild` accepts a second parameter for just that. So that would be `$newsXML->addChild('content', 'Wow it works!');`

Answer (score 22):

In PHP5, you should use the [Document Object Model](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) class instead.
Example:

```
$domDoc = new DOMDocument;
$rootElt = $domDoc->createElement('root');
$rootNode = $domDoc->appendChild($rootElt);

$subElt = $domDoc->createElement('foo');
$attr = $domDoc->createAttribute('ah');
$attrVal = $domDoc->createTextNode('OK');
$attr->appendChild($attrVal);
$subElt->appendChild($attr);
$subNode = $rootNode->appendChild($subElt);

$textNode = $domDoc->createTextNode('Wow, it works!');
$subNode->appendChild($textNode);

echo htmlentities($domDoc->saveXML());
```

Comment: DOM API is so verbose!  I'd love to be able to do something like `$elem->append($doc->p('This is a paragraph'));`  Even appending text is a two line chore.  I'd love something like `$elem->append('Some text');`

Comment: In my opinion it depends a lot on what you are planing to do. If you want basic and fast functionality, SimpleXML is perfect! But anyways: the question was "Using SimpleXML to create an XML object from scratch" - so off-topic, sorry.

Answer (score 16):

Please see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/139650/when-writing-xml-is-it-better-to-hand-write-it-or-to-use-a-generator-such-as-si#140203). As [dreamwerx.myopenid.com](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15487/dreamwerxmyopenidcom) points out, it is possible to do this with [SimpleXML](http://de.php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php), but the [DOM extension](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) would be the better and more flexible way. Additionally there is a third way: using [XMLWriter](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/intro.xmlwriter.php). It's much more simple to use than the DOM and therefore it's my preferred way of writing XML documents from scratch.

```
$w=new XMLWriter();
$w->openMemory();
$w->startDocument('1.0','UTF-8');
$w->startElement("root");
    $w->writeAttribute("ah", "OK");
    $w->text('Wow, it works!');
$w->endElement();
echo htmlentities($w->outputMemory(true));
```

By the way: [DOM](http://www.w3.org/DOM/) stands for **D**ocument **O**bject **M**odel; this is the standardized API into XML documents.

Comment: XMLwriter is good if you are intending to output directly to XML code without any manipulation.  Further manipulation (moving elements around, inserting elements) is not really possible.

Comment: Updated links (I think) http://php.net/manual/en/intro.xmlwriter.php, http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php