# how to add prefix and URI on xml objects (PHP)

Tags: php, xml, namespaces, uri, prefix

in this sample found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/143192/1154484):

```
<?php
$newsXML = new SimpleXMLElement("<news></news>");
$newsXML->addAttribute('newsPagePrefix', 'value goes here');
$newsIntro = $newsXML->addChild('content');
$newsIntro->addAttribute('type', 'latest');
Header('Content-type: text/xml');
echo $newsXML->asXML();
?>
```

We create an xml object from scratch. all righ.
my question is, how to embed a prefix in a tag during the construction of the object?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <soapenv:Header />
    <soapenv:Body>
        <EnviarLoteRpsEnvio xmlns="http://www.betha.com.br/e-nota-contribuinte-ws">
                           ...some important xml...
        </EnviarLoteRpsEnvio>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

in this code above, show a final xml, how, during the create of xml object, i embed the prefixes in the tags? sorry for my bugged english..
thanks for all help.

Comment: You probably want the [SOAP](http://php.net/manual/en/book.soap.php) extension instead of creating the XML manually.

Comment: Right, .. i'm trying to send through the soap but, the webservice that i want to integrate with my system, waits for a object as parameter, then i belive that is the only way to do it.