# Can PHP simpleXML be used to create a XML file?

Tags: php, simplexml

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using SimpleXML to create an XML object from scratch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/143122/using-simplexml-to-create-an-xml-object-from-scratch)

Can PHP simpleXML be used to create a XML file?

Comment: Yes, http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.asxml.php

Answer (score 0):

yes it can, thanks to the  `asXML` method