# How to create xml With Simplexml

Tags: php, xml, odbc

I have a database in MS Access with 3 columns (name,family,avg). Now, I want to read these columns and create XML for them with simplexml in PHP.

```
<Students>
<student>
<name></name>
<avg></avg>
</student>
<Students>
```

How can I do it?

Comment: What research's done by you? What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

Im not a moderator soo here is an old article hope it will be of some help :)
[Using SimpleXML to create an XML object from scratch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/143122/using-simplexml-to-create-an-xml-object-from-scratch)

Comment: i cant sync it with read from db,,,i know how can i read from db and know how can i create xml,,,but i cant sync them with together...PLEASE help me

Comment: Well :/ if you put it that way. what type of sync will you like ? give me all the detail please soo i can help you better

Comment: i said my db have 3 cols and the name them are name,family,avg...now i want to read from db and i know i can do it with a select command and run it with odbc_exec,,,after i read from my db,,,i want to create xml for my data
<Student><studen id=1><name>read col name first row from my db</name><avg>read col avg first row from my db</avg><student><studen><name>read col name first row from my db</name><avg>read col avg first row from my db</avg></Student>

Comment: ok to ensure were in the same wave do you know what is a asynchronous sync and a synchrnous sync :/ ?