# XML / PHP : Creation of a XML text with PHP

Tags: php, xml

I'm a beginner with XML on PHP. My page returns me the following PHP error:
[image: error on line 2 at column 1: Extra content at the end of the document]

But, at line 2, there only is a "require_once", followed by 3 others "require_once", the path to the required file is ok, and it ends with a ';'. The line above is the "

I have this sample of code, which I think is the source of this error (in this order)

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string("<result/>");
$entitlements = $xml->addChild("entitlements");
$entitlements->addChild("productId", $productId);
```

then, below :

```
$fulfillmentXML = new SimpleXMLElement($result);
//some stuff with $fullfillmentXML 
echo $xml->asXML();
```

I do not understand exactly how the XML works in PHP, but I thought there was a problem creating a SimpleXMLElement() after the simplexml_load_string() call.

Comment: you should put well formed xml to the simplexml_load_string(). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/143122/using-simplexml-to-create-an-xml-object-from-scratch

Comment: since line 2 is an include file, make sure that there is no output (space, line break, bom element).

Comment: This page should leave no questions: http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php

Comment: I have added the following code :
`header("Content-Type: application/xml");`

Answer (score 3):

Your error doesn't look like a PHP error, but rather a browser error generated when it tried to parse the supplied XML contents. Therefore line 2 of the error does not refer to line 2 of your PHP file, but to line 2 of your generated output.

Check your output (source of your generated page), and see what line 2 is there. Make sure you only have 1 root element, and that nothing comes after it.

Comment: How can i see the output source ? there is no text (of any kind) after the error I show in the screen, and inspecting the element with the browser only display the code from the error.

Comment: @APonelle Right click the page and do 'View Source' or open element inpector / firebug . And look in the Net Tab.