# Reaching the last XML element

Tags: php, xml

so I got this XML.
I got a lot of such similar blocks in XML, and I can loop through it. But how would I know how many blocks are there ?
Or how would I stop after the last block ?

Any suggestion is appreciated.

```
<StockBalanceOut xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2008/01/documents/BON_StockBalanceOut" class="entity">
<_DocumentHash>f5a598f180ccdecffeb7774d58ca8743</_DocumentHash>
<AvailPhysicalAvailableQty>0</AvailPhysicalAvailableQty>
<AvailPhysicalReservedQty>0</AvailPhysicalReservedQty>
<AvailPhysicalReturnQty>0</AvailPhysicalReturnQty>
<AvailPhysicalReworkQty>0</AvailPhysicalReworkQty>
<AvailPhysicalScrapQty>0</AvailPhysicalScrapQty>
<Date>2014-09-26</Date>
<ItemId>15742-20907</ItemId>
<ItemShippingClass>Empty</ItemShippingClass>
<OnOrderQty>0</OnOrderQty>
<PhysicalInventAvailableQty>0</PhysicalInventAvailableQty>
<PhysicalInventReservedQty>0</PhysicalInventReservedQty>
<PhysicalInventReturnQty>0</PhysicalInventReturnQty>
<PhysicalInventReworkQty>0</PhysicalInventReworkQty>
<PhysicalInventScrapQty>0</PhysicalInventScrapQty>
<RecId>5637416600</RecId>
<RecVersion>1</RecVersion>
<Time>15:25:52</Time>
</StockBalanceOut>
<StockBalanceOut xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2008/01/documents/BON_StockBalanceOut" class="entity">
<_DocumentHash>6c6a3aa160f3ab9388f8e1b5b2fd7dc1</_DocumentHash>
<AvailPhysicalAvailableQty>99</AvailPhysicalAvailableQty>
<AvailPhysicalReservedQty>0</AvailPhysicalReservedQty>
<AvailPhysicalReturnQty>0</AvailPhysicalReturnQty>
<AvailPhysicalReworkQty>0</AvailPhysicalReworkQty>
<AvailPhysicalScrapQty>0</AvailPhysicalScrapQty>
<Date>2014-09-26</Date>
<ItemId>21234-29752</ItemId>
<ItemShippingClass>Empty</ItemShippingClass>
<OnOrderQty>0</OnOrderQty>
<PhysicalInventAvailableQty>99</PhysicalInventAvailableQty>
<PhysicalInventReservedQty>0</PhysicalInventReservedQty>
<PhysicalInventReturnQty>0</PhysicalInventReturnQty>
<PhysicalInventReworkQty>0</PhysicalInventReworkQty>
<PhysicalInventScrapQty>0</PhysicalInventScrapQty>
<RecId>5637416601</RecId>
<RecVersion>1</RecVersion>
<Time>15:25:52</Time>
</StockBalanceOut>
```

Comment: Please show your current code for "looping through it"

Comment: When you say "blocks" what do you mean? XML tags?

Comment: @Steve
I cannot even start, as because I don't know the end parameter.

Comment: Have you looked at starting with something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/143122/using-simplexml-to-create-an-xml-object-from-scratch

Comment: @Mr.Concolato
Yeah, so one block is from `<StockBalanceOut>` to `</StockBalanceOut>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your XML, I got this information.
There are multiple 'blocks' for `<StockBalanceOut>`, you can access each one by :-

```
$objectOfXMLFile->StockBalanceOut[0];
$objectOfXMLFile->StockBalanceOut[1];
```

To reach till the end you can run a while loop. If any index (suppose 10 doesn't exist) for StockBalanceOut doesn't exist, then it will return null.

```
 $counter=0; //run from 0
    while(!is_null($xmlOBJ->StockBalanceOut[$counter]))
    {
//do anything here
    $counter++;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I would look at trying something like [this](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.count.php). To save you the link trip, here is some example code to get you started.

```
<?php
$xml = <<<EOF
<people>
 <person name="Person 1">
  <child/>
  <child/>
  <child/>
 </person>
 <person name="Person 2">
  <child/>
  <child/>
  <child/>
  <child/>
  <child/>
 </person>
</people>
EOF;

$elem = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);

foreach ($elem as $person) {
    printf("%s has got %d children.\n", $person['name'], $person->count());
}
?>
```